# Rythm template engine custom tags loading

Tags: java, web, template-engine, rythm

I have custom Rythm template tag (sayHi.html) which I want to call from parent template (index.html):

**In sayHi.html:**

```
Hi there!
```

**In index.html:**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>@sayHi()</body>
</html>
```

I have found out that default behaviour of Rythm template engine (v0.9) is that it tries to find custom template file in current application folder. Thus if I have web project running in Tomcat the path would be /TOMCAT_HOME/bin/sayHi.html

How could I tell Rythm to load custom tags from another path (e.g. /WEB-INF/tags)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can ask `Rythm` to load tags from anywhere:

```
Rythm.engine.loadTags(new File("/WEB-INF/tags"));
```

See source code [here](https://github.com/greenlaw110/Rythm/blob/master/src/main/java/com/greenlaw110/rythm/RythmEngine.java#L288)

You can also init `Rythm.engine` (or `RythmEngine` instance managed by yourself):

```
Properties conf = new Properties();
conf.put("rythm.tag.root", "/WEB-INF/tags");
Rythm.engine.init(properties); // use Rythm managed engine instance
myEngine = new RythmEngine(conf); // manage rythm engine instance by yourself
```

Note

1. Please be aware of [this](https://github.com/greenlaw110/Rythm/issues/20) issue since you are not using it with play
2. Please download latest distribution package from [rythm website](http://rythmengine.com)
3. The rythm document is not up to date. However you can get some new information from Play-Rythm documentation:

   - [version history](https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-rythm/blob/master/documentation/manual/history.textile)
   - [reference](https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-rythm/blob/master/documentation/manual/reference.textile)

**Updates**

Rythm has deprecated the tag concept, as now you can call any template as a "tag". See http://rythmengine.org/doc/template_guide.md#invoke_template